# How to set the dynamic height of table view cell with nested table views in ios.?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on a nested table view. with 3 table views one inside another, the two of the table views were working properly but the super table view's cells were not adjusting as per the respective content size. even I used. `UITableView.automaticDimension`

> 1st tableView in UIViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    let count = AllTaskManager.shared.futureListArray.count
    isNoData(count: count)
    print(count)
    return count
    
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FutureAppointCell") as! FutureAppointCell
    cell.setData(index: indexPath.row)
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    return UITableView.automaticDimension

}
```

> 2nd TableView inside the `FutureAppointCell`

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    tableHight.constant = CGFloat(AllTaskManager.shared.futureListDateArray.count * (Int(internalCellHeight) + 250))
    self.delegate?.cellHeight(tableHight.constant)
    return AllTaskManager.shared.futureListDateArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FutureAppoinmentDayCell") as! FutureAppoinmentDayCell
    cell.setData(index: indexPath.row)
    cell.delegate = self
    buttonTag = indexPath.row
    let startDate = AllTaskManager.shared.convertStringToDate(string: cell.dateFullName)
    print("\(startDate) is the date" )
    if startDate.month >= Date().month{
        if startDate.month == Date().month{
            if startDate.day == Date().day{
                cell.cancelBTN.isHidden = true
                cell.addToCalenderBTN.frame.size.width = 20
            }else{
                cell.cancelBTN.isHidden = false
                cell.cancelBTN.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelBtn(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            }
        }else {
            cell.cancelBTN.isHidden = false
            cell.cancelBTN.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelBtn(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }else {
        cell.cancelBTN.isHidden = true
    }
    cell.addToCalenderBTN.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addToCalendar(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

> 3rd Table view in `FutureAppoinmentDayCell`

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    tableHeight.constant = CGFloat(count * 65)
    self.delegate?.cellHeight(tableHeight.constant)
    return count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FutureNoBtnTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FutureNoBtnTableViewCell
    print(getDict(subIndex: indexPath.row))
    let dict = getDict(subIndex: indexPath.row)
    cell.employeeLBL.text = dict.value(forKey: "serviceDisplayName") as? String
    let time = AllTaskManager.shared.getSubHeaderTimeForPastFutureName(string:  dict.value(forKey: "startDateTime") as! String)
    cell.timeLBL.text = time
    cell.appointmentId = dict.value(forKey: "appointmentId") as? String
    cell.id = dict.value(forKey: "id") as? String
    cell.time = dict.value(forKey: "startDateTime") as? String
    if let startDate = dict.value(forKey: "startDateTime") as? String {
        let date = AllTaskManager.shared.convertStringToDate(string: startDate )
        if date.year == Date().year{
            if date.month == Date().month{
                if date.day == Date().day{
                    //"transitionStateDisplayValue": "Checked In",        "transitionStateDisplayValue": "Booked",
                    if let checkiInStatus = dict.value(forKey: "transitionStateDisplayValue") as? String{
                        cell.delegate = self
                        if checkiInStatus == "Checked In"{
                            cell.checkInBTN.isHidden = true
                            cell.checkedInLBL.isHidden = false
                        }else{
                            cell.checkInBTN.setTitle("Check-In", for: .normal)
                        }
                    }else{
                        cell.checkInBTN.isHidden = true
                    }
                }else {
                    cell.checkInBTN.isHidden = true
                }
            }else{
                cell.checkInBTN.isHidden = true
            }
        }else{
            cell.checkInBTN.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    return 60
}
```

Comment: Need more context please share your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [ask]. Your first step should always be searching... you'll find many, many results if you search for `uitableview in uitableviewcell swift`

Comment: Please share what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often use stack views in table view cells, and adjust cell height according to stack view. Maybe this will solve your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).